# How do I wire up a segue to the disclosure indicator on a cell which is not the first cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView with 4 static cells, and each cell has a disclosure indicator. The disclosure indicator should fire a segue. This works fine, but only for the first cell. I cannot figure out how to wire up a segue for anything but the first cell, either programmatically or via the story board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UITableView` delegate like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // row 1 corresponds to the second cell.
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegueID", sender: self)
    }
}
```

In the storyboard, create the segue from the first view controller (not from the cell itself) to the second view controller, and set its identifier to MySegueID``.